# optimal path graph algorithm with n movements

Tags: algorithm, graph, dynamic-programming, reinforcement-learning

I have a graph where each path has a unique a reward. For example, consider the below graph.

```
A: x => x*1
B: x => x-5
C: x => x*2
D: x => x/5

   A
 /   \
B --- C
 \   /
   D
```

Consider two paths, which have the same set of nodes but accrue different rewards, say the initial number at A is 10.

```
=====
[A -> B -> C -> D], reward: 2
A: 10*1 = 10
B: 10-5 = 5
C: 5*2 = 10
D: 10/5 = 2
=====
versus
=====
[A -> C -> B -> D], reward: 3
A: 10*1 = 10
C: 10*2 = 20
B: 20-5 = 15
D: 15/5 = 3
=====
```

Suppose two things:

1. The graph is much larger
2. At any given point, a player must make n movements. The goal isn't to find the best path from [A -> D] but to find the best path, with n movements, from [A -> some_node].

My questions are:

1. Can this task be accomplished with established graph algorithms or dynamic programming?
2. (Perhaps the above is no) Is reinforcement learning (such as Q-learning) required to find the optimal path with n movements?

edit:
Based on comments, this is an attempt at a subset of the algorithm, namely one that enumerates all possible paths:

```
def dfs(node, maxdepth):
    stack = [(node, 0)]
    paths = []
    p = []
    is_leaf = False
    
    while stack:
        node, nodedepth = stack.pop()
        p.append(node)
        
        if nodedepth < maxdepth:
            for neighbor in node.neighbors:
                stack.append(neighbor)
        
        else:
            is_leaf = True
        
        if is_leaf == True:
            paths.append(p)
            idx = p.index(node)
            p = p[0:idx]
            is_leaf = False
    
    return paths
```

Comment: It can be solved by an exhaustive search of all possible N-step paths.

Comment: @ScottHunter, anecdotally, of the tree and graph traversal algorithms I've seen, most have some sort of `visited` variable, where nodes are removed once arrived. Because it's permutations not combinations that are of interest here, I'm struggling to conceive of how to delineate all possible paths given a certain search depth.

Comment: You didn't say anything about nodes not being able to be re-used.  But if that is a requirement, then just keep a list of the nodes on the current path, at each step make sure the node being considered for the next step isn't in it.

Comment: No, nodes can be reused. My meaning was that I haven't seen a graph algorithm yet that does *not* leverage a visited variable. As such, I haven't come across a solution that I can adapt to my purpose yet. So, how would you enumerate all possible n-step paths?

Comment: Doing so would solve the problem.

Comment: @jbuddy_13 *"I haven't seen a graph algorithm yet that does not leverage a visited variable"* That's easy to fix. Start with the standard DFS algorithm, remove all mention of the visited variable, and limit the depth.

Comment: Are the reward functions all monotone?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat, as in monotonically increasing or decreasing? No-- the effects at each node, described in the first cell block, could increase or decrease the current reward at any step

Comment: @jbuddy_13 monotone as in if x increases, then f(x) doesn't decrease.